# Intellij Idea потеряла jdk после его обновления

Tags: intellij-idea, java

Раньше было установлено `jdk 1.7`. Затем, я установил `jdk 1.8`, а старый удалил. После чего пропали классы оболочки и запуск происходит с ошибкой:

> Error:Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\ssaan.IdeaIC2016.2\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл

Где поменять путь на `jdk 1.8`???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, а там во вкладке Project SDK выбирайте новую версию.
Обычно лежит в папке `C:\Program Files\Java\..`

Answer (score 9):

Файл -> Настройки проекта [image]

там укажешь какую версию. по умолчанию автоматом подтянет, а если нет - то создай через new

Answer (score 2):

`File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Project` -> `Project SDK` -> `new / edit` -> выставляешь путь до новой джавы